How can I solve this functional equation f(x)*f(y) = f(x) + f(y)
I'm trying to solve this functional equation for my own experimenting, but, I have no experience with functional analysis and have no idea how to solve this equation rigorously.
I'm trying to solve $f(x) \cdot f(y) = f(x) + f(y).$
I tried experimenting with exponential-related solutions and rational functions, but nothing seems to work.
How can I find the non-trivial solutions to this equation? Is there maybe a way derivatives could help too?

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult How to ask a good question for further guidance. PS: I didn't downvote.

Consider $x = y$. Then $(f(x))^2 = 2f(x)$. Then we see that $(f(x))^2 - 2f(x) = f(x)(f(x) - 2) = 0$. Then, for all $x$, we have either $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 2$. If $f(x) = 0$ for some $x$, then for all $y$, we have $0 = f(y)$. So, the two functions that are solutions are $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 2$.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

If the equation is to hold, you need the situation $x = y$ to hold as well. So $f^2(x) = 2f(x)$, and this needs to hold for all x. In that case f(x) = $2$ for all x is the only (would amend to other solution is f(x) = 0 is another solution) solution.
Just fyi, I did not study functional analysis so I can't talk on that front. If my answer is simply not appropriate I am assuming there is more advanced machinery I am supposed to use.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Not quite. All that you have shown so far, is that $ f(x) \in { 0, 2 }$ for each $x$. To reach your conclusion, you have to show that there doesn't exist a non-trivial partition of the reals, such that $f(x) = 0 , x \in A$ and $ f(x) = 2, x \in B$.

@CalvinLin Thank you, functional analysis is new to me so I thought I would tackle it from a real analysis background. It does make sense that I cannot deduce $f(x)$ is constant on the whole domain, given what we are told.
